# Mvvm light EventToCommand - Setting the Handled property?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, tabitem, eventtocommand

I have a tabbed GUI with each tab containing a Frame. I use the EventToCommand with the SelectionChangedEvent whenever a new TabItem is selected. I do this to update the state of the app. This all works fine - a little bit too fine, the event gets fired too often. Here is my problem:

How can I prevent the event from bubbling up the visual tree by setting the Handled property on the event when using the mvvm light eventToCommand feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
        <mvvm:EventToCommand
            Command="{Binding YourCommand}"
            PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Your command needs to provide parameter from method like  [RelayCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030)  . This parameter is event args providing Handled property. More [here](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/01/using-the-eventargsconverter-in-mvvm-light-and-why-is-there-no-eventtocommand-in-the-windows-8-1-version/).